# Python property files

Tags: python, properties, properties-file

I would like to make some property files in Python, like it is in Java (application.properties, application.yaml).

Is there any solution in Python project? Also I would like not to use some property parser, it would be great if something works out of the box like in Java.

Comment: Can't you simply create a py file serving as your properties file? what more do you need?

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to try and transfer the ways of one language into another one. It would be best if you stated what you want to do (and maybe why) and then learn the best way of doing that thing in the new language.

Comment: That is why I asked this question. I'm not sure what is a good practice in Python. Maybe it is py file, maybe some property file. In Java it is possible either way. I need to store some environment properties.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Python equivalent is the configparser to read INI files: https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html

It is similar, but not identical to properties files.

Example INI file, *example.ini* (copied from the linked documentation):

```
[DEFAULT]
ServerAliveInterval = 45
Compression = yes
CompressionLevel = 9
ForwardX11 = yes

[bitbucket.org]
User = hg

[topsecret.server.com]
Port = 50022
ForwardX11 = no
```

And a code example (also copied from the documentation):

```
>>> import configparser
>>> config = configparser.ConfigParser()
>>> config.sections()
[]
>>> config.read('example.ini')
['example.ini']
>>> config.sections()
['bitbucket.org', 'topsecret.server.com']
>>> 'bitbucket.org' in config
True
>>> 'bytebong.com' in config
False
>>> config['bitbucket.org']['User']
'hg'
>>> config['DEFAULT']['Compression']
'yes'
```

Comment: It is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!